# How to get a report of room mailboxes with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I tried to run this command. It runs smoothly but fields City and Country are not filled. What am I doing wrong?

```
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails RoomMailbox -ANR 'de-' | Select DisplayName,RecipientTypeDetails,alias,PrimarySmtpAddress,City,Country | export-csv C:\Output\room-de2.csv
```

[image]

Comment: if you run JUST the 1st section - the one that gathers info - and save that to a $Var, do you see those properties in the resulting object? if you do, are you sure that the names are the actual _property names_? the PoSh display system often renames the underlying items to make "display names". you can find the actual names using `Get-Member`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey how do i do that? I'm just a beginner in PS :(

Comment: @Ronald Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails RoomMailbox -ANR 'de-' | Get-Member

Comment: @Ronald - it looks like LukasRäpple has covered the "how to" of that. i _strongly_ suggest you learn to use  the help system that is built into PoSh. `Get-Help Get-Member -Examples` covers the idea quite neatly. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

`Get-Mailbox` returns a Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.Mailbox object. If you have a look at its [members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/ff341573(v=exchg.150)), City and Country are not there.

Both of those are (additional) members of the ADUser class. You will need to pass the SamAccountName property from the Get-Mailbox to Get-ADUser in a Powershell session with the ActiveDirectory module loaded. Without some more details about your environment, I can't advise you how do this in one go. But there is a multi-step method.

If you add SamAccountName to your `Select` pipeline you can use the CSV to do this. On a Domain Controller run

```
Import-Csv <path_to_CSV> | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName} | select City,Country | Export-Csv <new_CSV_path>
```

You can then add the two fields from the Get-ADUser output CSV to the Get-Mailbox CSV

```
$Exch = Get-Content <path_to_CSV>
$AD = Get-Content <new_CSV_path>
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $AD.Length; $i++) {$Exch[$i].insert(($Exch[$i].Length), ",$($AD[$i])") | Out-File <path_to_combined_csv> -Append}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! Your PS works perfectly but with one observation. I just had to add -properties city,co after $_.SamAccountName.
After trying to merge them into 1 csv, it works but all data is overwritten with the second csv. By the end, I have the report something like this:

#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser,#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser
City,"co","City","co"
,"Germany",,"Germany"